# how to export adobexd orientation scorlling prototype to Flutter with flutter plugin

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout, adobe-xd

I had created many prototypes in adobe xd with images that are scrollable with a landscape orientation and i used the flutter plugin but am unable to see the same exact prototype as I see in adobe xd, How can  i export the scroll feature from adobe xd to flutter?

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem .i also stuck with that